# How to read in this MongoDb field that contains dynamic children fields, in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Given the following MongoDB document structure (which I cannot change), I'm not sure how to read this in JavaScript?

[image]

- so `loginHistory` is the main field name. It contains an `Object` type (okay???)
- it can then contain multiple children fields (this above example has only ONE child), which are arrays. These field names are dynamic, but unique.
- the 'array' content is a C# `DateTimeOffset` , I've been told.

So in the example above, `Jane` is the field and the value is an `Array`, but really it's a `DateTime.Offset`.

Here's another document I've found:

[image]

- 4x fields

So i don't know how to read this with node/JavaScript. Oh - and the field `loginHistory` might not exist on some documents, also :(

So given that existing document schema/structure, I need to somehow read in each loginHistory value and then create a new document (which i'll do other stuff with later).

This is some JavaScript code I tried, but doesn't work:

```
    users.loginHistory.forEach(loginHistory => { 
        // do stuff, like create a new { id = users._id, name = "Jane", createdOn = "that date/time offset" }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming we have an input set of docs like the screen shots e.g.:

```js
var r = [
    {
        loginHistory: {
            "Jane": [ 1648835363929,  0 ],
            "Bob": [ 1648835363929,  0 ]
        }
    },
    {
        noLoginHistory: "nope"
    },
    {
        loginHistory: {
            "Dan": [ 1648835363929,  0 ],
            "Dave": [ 1648835363929,  0 ],
            "Jane": [ 1648835363929,  0 ]
        }
    }
];
```

then the following pipeline will create new, "converted" docs in a collection named `foo2`.

```js
db.foo.aggregate([
    // OK if loginHistory does not exist.  X will be set to null                     
    // and the $unwind will not produce anything:                                    
    {$project: {X: {$objectToArray: "$$ROOT.loginHistory"} }},
    {$unwind: "$X"},

    // Now we have individual docs of                                                
    //   X: {k: name, v: the array}                                                  
    // The OP wanted to make a new doc for each one.  I don't know                   
    // what function to apply to turn X.v[0] into a MongoDB datetime                 
    // because I don't know what that big int (637807576034080256) is                
    // supposed to be so I used regular ms since epoch for the example               
    // instead.  The OP will have to get more creative with division                 
    // and such to turn 637807576034080256 into something "toDate-able"              
    // in MongoDB.  You *could* store the big int as is but it is always             
    // good to try to turn a datetime into a real datetime in mongodb.               
    {$project: {
        _id: false,
        name: '$X.k',
        createdOn: {$toDate: {$arrayElemAt:['$X.v',0]}}
    }}

    // Now we have docs like :                                                       
    // {name: "Jane", createdOn: ISODate(...) }                                     
    // By calling $out to a new collection, a new _id will be assigned               
    // to each:                                                                      
    ,{$out: "foo2"}
]);
```

Comment: oh wow. this was so much more than what I was expecting! I was just hoping for a single JS line that says: "this is how u read the field" .. not actually some mongo-type script!

Works great! 

Now would I be able to request a tiny update to this? Each document has an `_id.userId`. I would love it if this could be the 3rd item in the 'new doc': `_id:false, userId: '$X.userId` or something.  (I would have asked in the OP but I wasn't expecting a answer using mongo aggregate (versus. mongo find and then pull the item out).

Comment: So '_id' in each original doc is an object e.g.  `_id: {userID: "buzz", other:"zzz"}`?

Comment: `_id: { userId: <guid> }`

Comment: Checking:   The *original* doc has `_id: {userID: <guid>}` and 1 or more `loginHistory` names.  So in `r[0]` in the answer above (Jane and Bob), do you want that `userID` *duplicated* into each broken out new doc?   In other words, flattening the structure?

Comment: thanks for sticking through this question, really appreciate it. I'm hoping to get a final result in the form of: `{ _id, name, createdOn }`. Which means I just need to change the 3rd stage from `_id:false` to `_id:true`. Then, I was going to try and see if I could add in -other existing- fields into the result document. Like this (for example) `{ _id, name, createdOn, age, favouriteTeam, blah1, blah2 }` ... if `age` `favouriteTeam`, etc are existing fields on the source document(s).

Comment: Understood -- but are you sure you acknowledge that by flattening `loginHistory` (i.e. putting name into a new separate document) you will dupe the other peer fields to `loginHistory`?   Perhaps it is best if you edit the question and change the screenshots to actual doc examples including `age`,`favouriteTem`, etc. and then show an example of exactly what 2 or 3 output documents would look like.

Comment: Oh @buzzmoschetti - for closure, the weird Date/Time value? It's a Long int, representing ticks from 1-1-0000 . (ref: https://github.com/EduBic/CSharp-Ticks-Date-Time-In-Javascript ) .. so I needed to also convert that ... as -correctly- suggested by you.